# Divide an int into whole numbers

Tags: java, math

I am looking for a way to divide an int into whole numbers. 
What I mean by this: if I have a number 30 and I want to divide this by 4, I want the output to be 8,8,7,7. 
Is there a way in Java to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is unclear. Why 8,8,7,7 and not 8,8,8,6 for instance? I'm voting to close it. Anyway, if you want an hint, you may want to look into *Genetics algorithms*.

Comment: @Aurasphere: Yes it's unclear but it's very likely that the implicit restriction is that the numbers differ by at most one. And no, genetic algorithms are not the best choice for such a simple problem.

Comment: @FrankPuffer if this is the problem, you are right, no genetic alghoritms. But I still think that this question should be edited or closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, Java is turing complete and therefore allows you to implement any algorithm.

I assume that the difference between the resulting numbers should be at most one - you did not explicitly write this.

Try this:

```
final int input = 30;
final int numberOfPieces = 4;    

final int quotient = input / numberOfPieces;
final int remainder = input % numberOfPieces;

int [] results = new int[numberOfPieces];
for( int i = 0; i < numberOfPieces; i++ ) {
    results[i] = i < remainder ? quotient + 1 : quotient;
}
```

This code first calculates the integer quotient and then equally distributes the remainder to the first "pieces".

Comment: Clear and quite simple solution. Thanks alot! Was looking all over the internet for this!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want equal splits of the number, what you may do is :

1. Divide the number by how many ever parts you want.
2. Round() the result
3. Add up the rounded of number how many ever times required & check if sum is same, if not add or subtract 1 as necessary.

Eg: N = 150 , parts = 4

=> 37.5 , Round it round(37.5) => 38

Now, 38*4 = 152 and 152-150 = 2 so subtract 2 from a number and your answer is 38, 38, 38 & 36.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        float number = 30.0f;
        float parts = 4.0f;    

        float val = number / parts;

        val = Math.round(val);
        if (val * parts == number){
            System.out.println("Numbers are:");
            for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
                System.out.println(val);
        }
        else {
            int diff = Math.round((val * parts) - number);
            System.out.println("Numbers are:");
            for(int i = 0;i < parts - 1; i++)
                System.out.println(val);
            System.out.println(val - diff);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Numbers are:
8.0
8.0
8.0
6.0
```

If you want to equally share the difference in the above case then just replace the else part with this:

```
else {
    int diff = Math.round((val * parts) - number);
     System.out.println("Numbers are:");
     for (int i = 0; i < parts - diff; i++)
         System.out.println(val);

     for (int  i = 0; i < diff; i++)
         System.out.println(val - 1);
}
```

Your output will be:

```
Numbers are:
8.0
8.0
7.0
7.0
```

Comment: Didn't the user want 8,8,7,7 in this case? And why do you complicate it by using floats?

Comment: Floats for the division. And "8,8,7,7" shall be obtained by using a loop at the end. I shall update the code for that.

Comment: Java has integer division that already solves part of the problem.

Comment: @FrankPuffer You would loose the decimal part if you use int.

Comment: Sure, but you can uuse the `%` operator for this, see my answer.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Yes that's a possibility. This is another possibility.